word choice: [given to us] or [given to our efforts]
I have written down the sentences below.
(1) Thank you very much for all the help and support you have given to our efforts. (I made it up.)
(2) Thank you very much for all the help and support you have given us. (My friends' revision)
My non-native friends think "our efforts" is wrong. I don't understand why. Can someone please explain that?

As between those two sentences, sentence 1 is not wrong, but I would certainly prefer sentence 2. I think that's because these supporters are supporting the person, not the activity. If the activity is important to mention, I would thank them "for supporting us in our efforts."

Neither of the sentences are grammatically wrong, but the second one is better in my opinion, since the referenced person will most likely have helped and supported you, and not your efforts. It is just that small difference in details, but there is definitely nothing wrong with the sentence you wrote.

Thank you very much for all the help and support you have given to our efforts. (I made it up.)

Person has helped and supported your efforts.

Thank you very much for all the help and support you have given us. (My friends' revision)

Person has helped and supported you.
